# z-index isn't working with relative parent & after/before elements

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

I have such code (prototype):

```css
.headerz {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5rem 0 0 5rem;
  margin: 3rem 0 0 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 24;
}

.headerz::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -3rem;
  background-color: red;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 22;
}

.headerz::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 72px;
  height: 66px;
  left: 8.5rem;
  top: -2.8rem;
  background-color: blue;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 22;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="headerz">Contacts</h3>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrLjqQ

why my red block isn't under the text?

Comment: Give the minus, -22 or something.

Comment: z-index is calculated from the closest parent positionned and within this parent . your z-index:22 value sets the pseudo on top (at 22) inside h3, not from the body. z-index:0 on pseudo is on the level of h3 .. starting at 24 ...

Comment: @VXp is it a good practice to set values < 0 ?

Comment: @brabertaser19 When you do you want that element unclickable or just presentational, yes!

Comment: Sure, nothing wrong with that, it's not about a good practice, it's usually about working / not working. :)

Comment: @VXp once its working you should start thinking about wheter its good or bad code still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `z-index: -1` on the before element.

```css
.footer-contacts-header-main {
position: relative;
padding: 5rem 0 0 5rem;
margin: 3rem 0 0 0;
color: #000;
font-size: 3.8rem;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 24;
}

.footer-contacts-header-main::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 110px;
height: 100px;
left: 0;
bottom: -3rem;
background-color: red;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
z-index: -1;
}

.footer-contacts-header-main::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 72px;
height: 66px;
left: 8.5rem;
top: -2.8rem;
background-color: blue;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
z-index: 22;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="footer-contacts-header-main">Contacts</h3>
```

Comment: Good one mate! `:)`

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar